# Django field to_python() method on ModelForm

Tags: django, django-forms

The `to_python` method of my custom field seems to not get called.

I have:

`models.py`

```
class FooURLField(models.URLField):
    def to_python(self, value):
        if value == u'http://':
            return u''
        return value


class Foo(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=128)
    url = FooURLField(blank=True)
```

`forms.py`

```
class FooForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        exclude = ['slug',]
```

I want the form to clear out the (default) value 'http://' if the url is left blank.
But the `to_python()` method never gets called. On a POST, it just goes straight to the `foo_form.is_valid()`.

I was under the impression that `to_python()` happens *before* the form gets cleaned.
I realize I could do it with javascript, but I'd rather do it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained in [the documentation for custom model fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-model-fields/#the-subfieldbase-metaclass); you need to add the `SubfieldBase` metaclass declaration.

However, this isn't really an appropriate use of a custom field. You should really do this in the form: either via a specific `clean_url` method or by providing a custom form field with its own `clean` method.

Comment: Got it. In order for `clean_url()` to fire, the field has to pass its _native_ validation first. So I have to make it a `CharField` and validate url myself, since "http://" fails url validation.

Comment: The link is broken